# Why is this the nearest integer?

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification

I was trying to prove that $(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^k$, where k is a positive integer, differs from the integer nearest to it by less than $(2N-\frac{1}{2})^{-k}$. Note: N is an integer greater than 1.

So, I tried to look for the answer of the question, which I have taken it from an exam paper.

It said that:
We let T=$(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^K +(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^{-k}$= $(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^k + (N-\sqrt{N^2-1})^k=2(N^k + kC2 N^{K-2}(N^2-1)+...$ which is clear it is an integer.

We know that: 
$(N-\frac{1}{2})^2 =N^2-N+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{4}-N$ This is <0 when N > 1, since N is an integer.

So, 
$N-\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{N^2-1}$.
$2N-\frac{1}{2} < N+\sqrt{N^2-1}$
$(2N-\frac{1}{2})^{-k}>(N+\sqrt{N^2-1}^{-k}$
Let $|T-(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^{-k}$| we would be able to prove the question.

However, my question is that, we need to have the nearest integer, so, the integer that the answer used is
 $(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^k + (N + \sqrt{N^2-1})^{-k}$.
Why is this the nearest integer?

Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: Sure, I will edit the question now. May I know what might my title be?

Comment: Hello, I have changed my question, could you guys check it?

Comment: Now that the OP has changed and enriched his question, it shouldn't any longer be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be a fixed integer.

Using the expression you give,

$$\underbrace{(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^k}_{A_k} + \underbrace{(N-\sqrt{N^2-1})^k}_{B_k>0}=\underbrace{2(N^k + \binom{k}{2} N^{k-2}(N^2-1)+...}_{C_k, \ \text{an integer}},\tag{1}$$

$C_k$ will be the closest integer to $A_k$ if their difference $B_k=C_k-A_k$ is proven to be $< 1/2$, whatever the values of $N>1$ and $k>0$ ;

Indeed :

$$B_k=N(1-\sqrt{1-1/N^2})^k < N(1-(1-1/N^2))^k=1/N^{2k-1} \leq 1/2^{2k-1}<1/2$$

due to inequality

$$\sqrt{1-x} < 1-x$$ valid for any $x$ such that $0 < x < 1$.

Remarks :

a) Let us show a numerical example in the case $N=2$ , with columns $k, A_k, B_k, C_k$ in that order :

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
   1&3.732050807 &  0.267949192  & 4\\
   2&13.928203230 &  0.071796769  & 14\\
   3&51.980762113 &  0.019237886 &  52\\
   4&193.994845223 &  0.005154776  & 194\\
   5&723.998618781  & 0.001381218  & 724\\
   6&2701.999629903 &  0.000370096 &  2702\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

It is to be noted that numbers $C_k$ obey a second order recurrence relationship :
$$C_{k+1}=4 C_k-C_{k-1}\tag{2}$$

(see https://oeis.org/A003500) and more generally :

$$C_{k+1}=2N C_k-C_{k-1}$$

(it comes from the fact that $A_k$ and $B_k$ can be considered as the two roots of quadratic characteristic equation associated with (2).

b) [in connection with (a)] : (1) can be considered for example as the analog of Binet formula for Fibonacci sequence defined by second order recurrence :

$$F_{k+1}=F_k+F_{k-1}$$

http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html#section1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I still don't quite understand why if B is smaller than half is a necessary and sufficient condition to be in the 'reach' of the targeted integer number C

Comment: I mean that if a real number $A$ and an integer $C$ are such that their difference $B:=C-A < 1/2$, $C$ is the closest integer to $A$...

Comment: I have (slightly) corrected my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much; but, why is that so.....I still don't understand . Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: I mean that if you are in a situation like $7.6+0.4=8$, you can say that the closest integer of $7.6$ is $8$. We are here always in this situation. The "gap" function expressing the difference between a real number ans its closest integer has a sawtooth profile with a maximum value $1/2$.

Comment: Sure， thank you very much. But what if it is like 7.3+0.4 + 0.4. Then, it would not be the closest integer?

Comment: Finally, I quite get it.  This is because the two terms added together would always be an integer.

Comment: You have thus understood that $7.2+0.4+0.4$ will never occur in fact. I have added a numerical example to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

By induction on $k$, we have
$$ (N\pm \sqrt{N^2-1})^k=a\pm b\sqrt{N^2-1}$$
with $a,b\in\Bbb Z$.
And of course
$(N-\frac12)^2=N^2-N+\frac14<N^2-1 $ implies
$$ 2N-\frac12<N+\sqrt{N^2-1}<2N.$$
Now from 
$$ (N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^k(N-\sqrt{N^2-1})^k=((N+\sqrt{N^2-1})(N-\sqrt{N^2-1}))^k=1^k=1,$$
we conclude that $(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^k=a+b\sqrt{N^2-1}$ differs from the integer $2a$ by
$$a-b\sqrt{N^2-1}=\frac1{(N+\sqrt{N^2-1})^k}<\frac1{(2N-\frac12)^k}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Given that $\,N>1\,$ is an integer, 
define the real numbers 
$\, u := (N+\sqrt{N^2-1}),\,$
$\, v := (N-\sqrt{N^2-1}),\,$
and thus $\,u+v=2N, u\,v=1.\,$
Define the sequence
$\, a(n) := u^n+v^n.\,$
This sequence satisfies $\,a(n) = a(-n)\,$ and a
 linear recurrence
$\, a(n+1) = 2Na(n)-a(n-1) \,$
both for all integer $\,n\,$ with
$\,a(0) = 2\,$ and $\,a(1) =2N.\,$ Thus all
$\,a(n)\,$ are positive even integers.
Read the Wikipedia article [Lucas sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence) for many details 
about such sequences.

Now notice that $\,0<v<\frac12\,$
and so $\,0<v^n<\frac12\,$ for all positive integer $\,n.\,$ Thus
$\,a(n)\,$ is the closest integer to
$\,u^n\,$ and $\,u^n=a(n)-v^n
.\,$